# Prolog: how to transpose non-rectangular matrices by padding

Tags: list, prolog

As of right now, I use the following code for transposing rectangular matrices.

```
trans(L,[Head|Tail]) :-
   list_first(L,Head,A),
   trans(A,Tail).
trans(Empty,[]) :-
   empty(Empty).

empty([[]|Tail]) :-
   empty(Tail).
empty([[]]).

list_first([[Head|A]|Rest],[Head|Heads],[A|As]) :- 
   list_first(Rest,Heads,As).
list_first([],[],[]).
```

How can I make it work with "jagged" list of lists like `[[a,b,c],[1,2]]`, as used below, too?

Sample query:

```
?- trans([[a,b,c],[1,2]], T).
false.                           % desired answer: T = [[a,1],[b,2],[c,[]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would stay with some 'reusable' utilities, preprocessing the Lists and ensure all have the same length:

```
lists_length_max(ListS, LenS, MaxLen) :-
    maplist(length, ListS, LenS),
    max_list(LenS, MaxLen).

list_padding(MaxLen, ElemPad, List, Len, Padded) :-
    LenTail is MaxLen - Len,
    length(Tail, LenTail),
    maplist(=(ElemPad), Tail),
    append(List, Tail, Padded).

trans_padding(ListS, Trans) :-
    trans_padding(ListS, Trans, []).
trans_padding(ListS, Trans, PadElem) :-
    lists_length_max(ListS, LenS, MaxLen),
    maplist(list_padding(MaxLen, PadElem), ListS, LenS, Padded),
    trans(Padded, Trans).
```

now, trans_padding/2 should be called instead of trans/2

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation:

```
row([], [_|_], [], []).
row([[]|Rs], A, NewRs, [[]|Cs]) :-
    row(Rs, A, NewRs, Cs).
row([[X|Xs]|Rs], A, [Xs|NewRs], [X|Cs]) :-
    row(Rs, [X|A], NewRs, Cs).

transpose(Rows, [T|Ts]) :-
    row(Rows, [], Rest, T),
    transpose(Rest, Ts).
transpose(Empty, []) :-
    maplist(=([]), Empty).
```

`transpose` operates a row at a time. The `row` predicate uses an auxiliary argument (the third one) to ensure that it terminates without generating phantom rows that are all empty elements. The call to `maplist(=([]), Empty)` is a short-hand for the predicate `empty/1` defined in the question.